# How to fit WPF MenuItem's size based on it child's size

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, menuitem

I have context menu. One of menuitems contains combobox.
When the menu item w/ combobox is rendered menuitem is much wider then the combo box.
[image: Snap shot w/ the issue]
Any ideas how I can set menu item's size to be snaged to the combobox.
Here is how I create the menu and combobox:

```
XamComboEditor combo = new XamComboEditor();
combo.ItemsSource = Context.RecipientOptions;
combo.DisplayMemberPath = "Display";
combo.IsEditable = true;
combo.MinWidth = 250;
combo.DropDownResizeMode = PopupResizeMode.None;
combo.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
combo.LimitToList = false;
combo.SetBinding(XamComboEditor.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding("Recipient") 
                 {Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay});
MenuItem comboMenu = new MenuItem {Header = combo, StaysOpenOnClick = true, 
                                   RenderSize = combo.RenderSize,};
menu.Items.Add(comboMenu);          
MenuItem removeMenu = new MenuItem {Header = "Remove this recipient"};
removeMenu.Click += (sender, e) => RemoveRecipient();
removeMenu.IsEnabled = ActionSet.Actions.Count > 1 || Recipient != null;

menu.Items.Add(removeMenu);
```

I tried to set RenderSize but in runtime it is zero.

Thank you.

Comment: realized that i forgot to change HorizontalAlignment to Stretch after playing around w/ it.

Comment: in order to remove that space you have to edit the control template of the MenuItem control. There is space allocated for the InputGestureText, the icon that shows you there are children of this item and so on.

Comment: Olimpiu, Thank you and sorry for delay in reply, I did not know you answered, I thought I'll get notification when there is a reply. Do you have an example of how to do it by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms747082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a link from a MenuItem ControlTemplate example from Microsoft. You can edit this one to obtain the desired aspect.
For example in this xaml:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Border Name="Border" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter Name="Icon" Margin="6,0,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon"/>
            <Border Name="Check"  
                    Width="13" Height="13" 
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Margin="6,0,6,0" 
                    Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}">
                <Path Name="CheckMark"
                      Width="7" Height="7" 
                      Visibility="Hidden" 
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
                      Stroke="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
                      StrokeThickness="2"
                      Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0" />
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderHost"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              ContentSource="Header"
                              RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
                        Margin="5,2,0,2"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsCheckable" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Check" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

you can edit the Grid.CollumnDefinitions to resize or even remove some columns if you don't need them.
If you add the controlTemplate from the link in a separate ResourceDictionary (which I recommend you to do), don't forget to add it also in the MergeDictionaries from your App.xaml file to make it visible in the entire application. 
Here is how to do this if you add it directly in the root of your app:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/YourApplicationName;component\MenuStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I hope this might help you solve your problem.

Comment: I created separate xaml file and added inside my control <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../../LimitResources.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../../MenuItemTemplateResources.xaml" />
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> however TryFindResource(new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(MenuItem), "SubMenuItemCombo")); can't find it, any ideas?

Comment: I succeed only when I load it "manually" to window's MergedDictionaries

Comment: is there a ControlTemplate with the x:Key="SubMenuItemCombo" in your resourceDictionaries?

Comment: Yes, I defined in MenuItemTemplateResources.xaml, the issue is that code is looking up the template in Model's RelayCommand which does not have reference to any control (as I think it should be) except to a window....

Comment: Try getting your resource like this: var searchedControlTemplate = Application.Current.Resources["SubMenuItemCombo"];.

Comment: still can't find it; I posted it as separate question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946337/how-can-code-find-resource-in-model-that-does-not-have-access-to-user-control Thank you

Comment: in this case you have to search for the resource in the UserControl where you have created it. This is why is good to have the resources merged in the App.xaml, so you can have access to them from the entire application. I have tested the solution I sent you before posting it and it functioned well.